# How to order a LinQ result set created by a list of ID and order it use existing order of the list

Tags: linq, sorting

My code is something like this:

```
List<int> IDs = new List<int> {9,7,38, 23}
IQueryable<Post> pp = myDataEntity.Posts.Where(p=>IDs.Contains(p.ID));
```

How can I explain that I want to sort pp by the order of ID in the IDs? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order by [`List.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bd0tetb.aspx):

```
IQueryable<Post> orderedPosts myDataEntity.Posts
    .Select(p  => new { Post=p, Index=IDs.IndexOf(p.ID) })
    .Where(x   => x.Index >= 0)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Index)
    .Select(x  => x.Post);
```

Comment: This seems to be what I need. I need a little bit more time before confirming (not at the computer right now). Can you clear a little bit more about ".Where(x   => x.Index >= 0)", in which case x.Index can be <0? thank you.

Comment: @user2742377: [`List.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bd0tetb.aspx) returns `-1` if an element was not found in the collection. So you can use it for both, determine if it's contained and at which index (for the order). I have used the anonymous type to store this value, otherwise i would need it twice(`Where` + `OrderBy`).

Comment: ah, that case happens when the ID is not in IDs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to keep the order of ID you have in IDs and not actually the ordered verison of it, this is how you can do it:

```
var pp = IDs.Select(x=> myDataEntity.Posts.Where(p=>p.ID == x))
            .SelectMany(x=>x);
```

Using IDs as your external collection, you get to keep the ordering of the elements in it.

Answer (score 0):

use [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548916.aspx)

```
IQueryable<Post> pp = myDataEntity.Posts.Where(p=>IDs.Contains(p.ID))
                                        .OrderByDescending(p => p.ID)
```

Comment: I think he wants to keep the order as it is in IDs ( first the match with 9, then the match with 7, then 38, then 23) , not the ordered version of it